# Parse through multiple values in string variable that are separated by commas

Tags: php, string, variables, loops, for-loop

I have a string variable that has multiple values in the following format:

```
123, xyz, abc
```

It may even have a single value only (in that case there wont be any comma after it)

How do I parse through these values in a `for` loop, going over each value at a time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$input="123, xyz, abc"; 
foreach (explode(",",$input) as $value) { 
    var_dump(trim($value)); 
}
```

Comment: the code does not work when the variable has just a single value without any comma after it- what do I do in that case? (I ran your code and checked).

Comment: It works fine here:
    $input="123"; foreach (explode(",",$input) as $value) { var_dump(trim($value)); }
string(3) "123"

Comment: sorry- my echo statement had a problem :( it works fine :) thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Try to **explode** with comma '**,**' like

```
$your_arr = "123,xyz,....";
$my_arr = explode(",",$your_arr);
foreach($my_arr as $arr) {
      echo $arr;
      //Do the stuff HERE
}
```

Comment: it works fine :) thanks- but i can only accept one answer as the right one :(